# Dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 on UEFI laptop

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader, uefi

I have a notebook pre-installed with Windows7 and I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it following the standard installation steps in the installation image.

The only problem is that on reboot the machine continues to boot Windows ignoring the presence of Ubuntu (Grub never comes up).

My partition scheme is this

```
sda1: NTFS 612MB
sda2: NTFS 50GB (after resizing during Ubuntu installation. This is the main windows partition)
sda4: extended
sda5: ext4 /boot
sda6: btrfs /
```

I have tried **Boot-repair** and it didn't help. Tried **rEFInd** boot manager but it doesn't support NTFS partitions.

I don't know what else to try. My next attempt is to try to install GRUB by hand to the MBR.

Any other Ideas?

Comment: Please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

If the partition data you presented is accurate, you are *not* booting in UEFI mode. The computer may support UEFI boots, but most UEFI computers also include a compatibility feature that enables them to boot in BIOS/legacy mode, and my hunch is that's what you're using.

To better diagnose this, I recommend you download the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and run it from a live CD. Post a link to the RESULTS.txt file that the script generates. This information will tell us how GRUB is installed, give us more details about your partitions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, and a few more... This is how I sorted it out:

I finally sorted it, after understanding a few things and doing:

Installing Ubuntu (you have done that already)

Creating a Live-USB or LIVE-CD (I did it with Universal-USB-Installer)

running Live USB (just restarting your computer for CD, otherwise entering BIOS and selecting usb for booting)

Installing and running boot-repair from Dash Home->terminal with:

Locating boot-repair with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Updating with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Installing it with:

```
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

- GRUB came out here

Then I logged and couldn't click on anything until I:

Selected Ubuntu Classic/2D in login screen.

- Here I was able to click on things after

Updating with Software Up to date at the top right hand corner

Restarting and selecting normal mode

Hope it helps, I just fixed it two hours ago!